# Very basic question re Many to Many queries MS-Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

Apologies in advance for the banal and basic nature of this question, but I'm brand new to Access. I've searched my Access books and bibles, online, etc and cannot solve this very simple problem:

I have a many to many relationship set up for Employees and Events they may attend. An employee can attend many events. An event can be attended by many employees. I have no trouble writing a query to list Employees who have been on - say - Event A **OR** Event C. What I can't do is write a query to list employees who have been on (for example) Event A **AND** Event C.

I have three tables:

**Employee**. Key: EmployeeId. (*Also contains name, position, etc*)

**EmployeeEvent**. Keys: ID, EmployeeID

**Event**. Key:EventID (*Also contains event name, date etc*)

Employee links to EmployeeEvent on Employee.EmployeeID=EmployeeEvent.EmployeeID

Event links to EmployeeEvent on Event.EventID=EmployeeEvent.ID

 No problem with OR queries. Simply don't know how to make AND queries work.

This is my first ever post, many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A brute force way would be to do a union:

```
Select employeeID, EventID from EmployeeEvent
where employeeID = 9999999 and eventID = 8888

Union

Select employeeID, EventID from EmployeeEvent
where employeeID = 9999999 and eventID = 7777
```

The "Union" will get rid of any duplicates in the results.  "Union All" will preserve any duplicates.

This query will not show up in your visual query editor.  It will say something like "Cannot display", but it should run.

You could also do two select queries, one for each Employee/Event combination you're looking for, then link the two queries in an inner join. The employees who went to both events should show in the results.  Just depends on how you want to see  your results.

Comment: Many thanks for this. 'Union' will be useful to me definitely. But given the potential final complexity of the application - a lot of MTM relationships, Employee, Project, Courses, Events etc etc requiring queries with massive nesting of SQL -  I'm going to use VBA, which I feel much more confident with.

Comment: Ok.  The joining of two tables in an inner join, and each table filtered to what you need the AND for, might be more flexible than the union.  You could consider parametrized queries, where it will ask you for parameters when it runs. If you don't know how to do that, I'll explain.  I just prefer to do queries over coding whenever possible.